# How to display table-cell on a single line (IE6-IE7)?

Tags: html, css

I am aware of compatibility issues-cell display in IE6-IE7, my goal is to display on the same line two divs display-cell. On all browsers except IE6-IE7 the two divs are displayed on the same line. I noticed one thing though, putting in quirks mode * float: left to the first div, the divs are shown on the same line. How to put them on the same line without using the quircks mode with only css?

Comment: We need code examples, ideally a jsfiddle or codepen sketch, to be able to help you.

Comment: display: table-cell doesn't work in older browsers..you'd have to fallback on IE6-IE7 hacks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ySTf/ why with quirks mode and *float: left on #r1 works with IE6-IE7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this css:

```
body{
    margin: 0
}
#table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    *overflow:auto;
}
#r1{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    *float:left;

}
#r2{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    *float:left;
}
```